# Why are the matplotlib figures showed differently/wrongly in PyCharm and Spyder IDE than how they are being shown in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, spyder, figure

I am trying to display my matplotlib figures in Pycharm or Spyder IDE so I am using my Jupyter Notebook's code. However, the figures in the IDEs are shown wrongly.

For example, in the Jupyter notebook, the figure is displayed like this:
[Displayed Figure on Juyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEx6M.png)

On the other hand, if I run the same code on Pycharm or Spyder IDEs, the figure is displayed like this:
[Displayed Figure on Pycharm & Spyder IDEs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8q5u.png)

I don't think the environment that my code is ran affects the code in any way. However, I will still add the code below.

```
# Data Visualisation

# countplot of every variable
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
plt.figure(i) # create a figure for each feature of the dataset
sns_plot = sns.countplot(x=col, data=df) # plot the figure for the specific feature and 
                                         # its corresponding values
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the default size of the plot is different between Jupyter and the IDEs.